# Search data from table column using regex in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I need to seach data from table with person`s phone number. But phone number is saved in different forms. But its length equals to 9 and only consist of numbers. How can I find number  when I search with static form like `998732387`  then result should be.

`2         |  99 873 23 87  | Kike`

When I enter `971234573` then result should look like below:

`3         |  97 123-45-73  | Cris`

`mytable`

```
-----------------------------------------
id        |   phone        | name
----------------------------------------
1         |  991234567     | Michael
2         |  99 873 23 87  | Kike
3         |  97 123-45-73  | Cris
```

Please Help me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to remove all non-digits:

```
select *
from mytable
where regexp_replace(phone, '[^[:digit:]]', '') = '971234573';
```

Comment: Thank you bro this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Or, if your database doesn't support regular expressions (hard to believe), `translate` does the job:

```
SQL> with test (id, phone, name) as
  2    -- your sample data
  3    (select 1, '991234567', 'Michael' from dual union all
  4     select 2, '99 873 23 87', 'Kike' from dual union all
  5     select 3, '97 123-45-73', 'Cris' from dual
  6    ),
  7  only_digits as
  8    -- remove non-digits from the PHONE colunmn (pre-regex version)
  9    (select id, phone, name,
 10       translate(phone, 'a' || translate(phone, 'x0123456789x', 'x'), 'a') digit
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  select id, phone, name
 14  from only_digits
 15  where digit = '998732387';

        ID PHONE        NAME
---------- ------------ -------
         2 99 873 23 87 Kike

SQL>
```